# Coherent sheaf with big enough support is non-zero in K-theory

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

Let $X$ be a noetherian, separated, integral scheme of dimension $d < \infty$ and $\mathcal F \in \mbox{Coh}(X)$ coherent sheaf on $X$ with support $\operatorname{Supp} \mathcal F = X$. Is it true that $0 \neq [\mathcal F] \in {K'_0}(X) := K_0(\mbox{Coh}(X))$? How one can provide a simple counterexample?

Comment: The image of $\mathcal F$ in the $K'_0$ of the generic point is non-zero (equal to the rank).

Comment: Thank you! But how this consistent with the nontriviality of Serre's positivity conjecture? If I am not wrong, the conjecture asked to prove that for any f.g. $R$-modules $M,N$, over local ring $(R,m)$, with appropriate supports, the number $\chi(M,N) = [M]\cdot[N] = [M \otimes N] \in {K'_0}^{\{m\}}(\operatorname{Spec} R) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is positive? Coherent sheaf associated to $M \otimes N$ is naturally non-zero coherent sheaf on point $\{m\}$, and by your argument, it must be positive in K-theory, so, where is the problem?

Comment: The equality $[M].[N] = [M\otimes N]$ is not true unless you assume strong extra conditions.

Comment: @HailongDao I see, I misconceived a little how the general theory work. Thank you!